# how to display child div's inline-block while parent container is display flex?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble displaying my child div tags side-by-side while the parent div tag is display flex, if anyone can show me how to get this to work, that would be great! Here's my code sample:

css

```
    .wrapper{
    z-index: +1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.wrapper .logo{
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
}
.wrapper .logo img{
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper .discription{
    width: 320px;
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
}
.wrapper .discription h1{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.wrapper .links{
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
}
.wrapper .links nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper .links nav ul li{
    display: block;
}
.wrapper .links nav ul li a{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

html

```
   <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/fire-engine.png" draggable="false">
        </div>
        <div class="discription">
            <header>
                <h1>Best non-host mw2 menu cheat engine [cex/dex]</h1>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">support</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

what I'm trying to do, similar to this:
[image]

Comment: can you show us the html?

Comment: @CharlieNg here you go: https://pastebin.com/cLPXrgp8

Comment: In your question, I see "what I'm trying to do:" but nothing else. Do you miss something such as images?

Comment: @shaochuancs yea, i uploaded an image, but it didn't show for some reason, here is the image i was trying to show http://image.prntscr.com/image/33ddebbad75e4b20a25d6c44352bafd3.png

Comment: make `flex-direction` as `row` if all you want is align child divs horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep `display: flex` and remove `flex-direction: column` in your .wrapper because flex-direction by default is row when you have `display: flex`.

```
.wrapper{
    z-index: +1;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nL27af3z/1/